# Datatable-Sorting

Tags: jquery, sorting, datatable, using

In my program Iam using jquery pagination with help of  http://www.datatables.net/.
but in one of my table data is displaying,but when i click on table head for sorting data is cleared shos no data available.

Answer (score 0):

You must declare sort in init.
For example:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('#example').dataTable( {
        "bPaginate": true,
         "bSort": true
         } );
} );
```

Also you must try add  tags for your table head.

```
<table id="example">
<thead>
<tr>
<td>name</td>
<td>surname</td>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<tr>
<td>Jack</td>
<td>Brown</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: for some tables only it is data is displayed.for some table it is working properly. /@@@@@ "bPaginate": true,
         "bSort": true  @@@/ already done this.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not 100% sure without seeing any sort of code that you've implemented but it sounds like a problem with your server-side sorting code.

There is however [this](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/155422/jQuery-DataTables-and-ASP-NET-MVC-Integration-Part), which links to a series of really helpful articles on integrating jQuery Datatables with ASP.NET MVC. It goes through how to perform searching/sorting of different columns of data as well as pagination. The only thing it doesn't really do is go into depth about how to do multi-column sorting (I'm still trying to work this out). The below jQuery artificially stops multi-column sorting if you still want to maintain singular column sorting (its a bit cheap but it does the job temporarily).

```
//Disable multi-column sorting when holding shift
$('#tblExample thead th').click(function (event) {
    if (!$(event.target).hasClass('sorthandle')) {
        event.shiftKey = false;
    }
    else {
        event.shiftKey = false;
    }
});
```

Hope this helps :).